# Casting method parameters in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, types, casting

#### Update

Okay, first of all, thank you all for the huge amount of activity. It seems that I did not phrase my question too well, since many of the answers got (rightfully) stuck on the `id` input parameter, and following poor design patterns, but it was merely an example. I'll add some context to my question:

- Suppose that there are multiple different implementations for `doSomethingWithParameter:`, requiring a specific instance as input parameter
- My class in the example will *only ever* get called with an instance of `SpecificClass` as input parameter

With these assertions, here is my assumption: Given, that you *know* the type of the parameter, there is no benefit in type checking and casting, just for the sake of extra safety.

#### Original post

Suppose I have a general method in my protocol declaration, which takes an `id` input parameter:

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>

- (void)doSomethingWithParameter:(id)inputParameter;

@end
```

In a class, which conforms to `MyProtocol`, I usually prefer making the type of `inputParameter` explicit like so:

```
- (void)doSomethingWithParameter:(SpecificClass *)inputParameter
{
    /... do something with param
}
```

Occasionally I received critique for choosing this solution, as opposed to the following:

```
- (void)doSomethingWithParameter:(id)inputParameter
{
    if ([inputParameter isKindOfClass:[SpecificClass class]]) {
        SpecificClass *myInstance = (SpecificClass *)inputParameter;
        /... do something with param
    }
}
```

I really prefer the first version, since it clearly states the parameter my instance is expecting. It is more concise, and clear. I generally don't think I can gain much from type checking/casting.

My question: from a coding standard standpoint, which one is the better solution? Does the first one have any disadvantages?

Comment: `ARC` will be disappointed by your first approach, it has an innocent question for you `le why you no make it type safe`

Comment: I understand the benefit of creating a typed input parameter, I would definitely go that way in my own projects. This is a very specific example, where I'm looking to learn. :)

Answer (score 5):

### Update

From the update to your question, it seems that you are trying to achieve some variation of a functionality provided by the generics in modern languages.

Since `Objective-C` does not support this pattern, you can either sacrifice type safety, or rethink your design decisions.

If you go the first way, you should make it **really** clear by other means (naming, documentation) what types are you expecting. Then it might be reasonable to assume that your method will only be called with proper params.

But I would still add `NSParameterAssert` to simplify future debugging.

---

### Original Answer

If you are using the first approach, you have a mismatch between declaration and definition of the method. Due to dynamic nature of obj-c (method signature does not include types of parameters), compiler does not complain about it.

However, when calling the method, only declaration is visible, so any information about the type of parameters is derived from that - all the type checking (yes, here compiler does it) is performed based on declaration.

In conclusion, to avoid confusing bugs and misuse of API, you should definitely use the second approach. Or change declaration together with definition.

**Edit**

Also, I can think of third solution, that somewhat merges convenience of the first approach with type safety of the second one:

```
- (void)doSomethingWithParameter:(SpecificClass *)inputParameter
{
    NSParameterAssert([inputParameter isKindOfClass:[SpecificClass class]]);

    // do something
}
```

Comment: I would also add that it's a bad practice for a method to accept parameters of different types (typically JSON encoders can accept both and array and a dictionary). It makes the code harder to read and maintain. It's always the best to give a specific type because the intent of the method is then obvious.

Comment: @Sulthan It depends on the method. For example for actions it is pretty good, because the sender should be any object. It is the same with the responder chain, going through different layers of MVC to solve some problems. Indeed, there is no reason to have such "open parameter types" as a concept for your whole code.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when you use `id` for a parameter type that means either that type may vary or you may  invoke method with ambiguous parameter. For both cases, second one is preferred as it checks type and prevents unwanted crash.

If you prefer the type of `inputParameter` explicit then simply define it in the protocol, like

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>
- (void)doSomethingWithParameter:(SpecificClass *)inputParameter;
@end
```

and for this forward declaration you may have to import module/class, like

```
#import "SpecificClass.h" // import class
```

OR

```
@class  SpecificClass; // import module
```

Comment: Well, it has an `id` parameter for a reason: specific implementations may expect different types. _This particular implementation_ requires an instance of `SpecificClass`, and that is the only class it should be passed. The implementation here will make it clear that for this instance, the method should only be called with a `SpecificClass` param, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Then I will suggest the second approach where type is checked.

Answer (score -2):

What you do is perfectly fine. If your method is called with a parameter that is an instance of the wrong class, that is a bug in the caller. In Objective-C, you don't work around bugs, you make them crash your code, and then you fix the bug (that is why nobody handles exceptions, exceptions are bugs in your code and when they crash your code, the cause of the exception needs to be fixed).

This is much more common when you pass blocks, for example a block testing array elements, where you know exactly what type of array to expect.